# Approximate solution of the following integral

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-numbers, approximation, laguerre-polynomials

I have the following integral.

$$ G(q) = \int_{0}^{\infty} y^\alpha \exp(-y) \exp(-j b q\exp(-c y)) dy $$

with
$$ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+, \quad q, b, c  \in \mathbb{R}, \quad  j = \sqrt{-1}$$

I have asked this before in different forms, but I have settled down with the following approximation using Gauss-Laguerre Polynomial.

$$ G(q) = \sum_{i = 1}^n w_i f(y_i), $$

where,
$$ w_i = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + n + 1)y_i}{n! (n+1)^2 [L^{\alpha}_{n+1}(y_i)]^2} $$
$$ f(y) = \exp(-j b q\exp(-c y)) $$

And $y_i$ are the zeros of the Laguerre polynomial $L_n^{\alpha}(x)$. To compute this faster (as I need to compute it for several $q$, $\alpha$, and $c$ combinations), I have stored the zeros of $L_n^{\alpha}(x)$ in a matrix form for several $\alpha$ values.

The questions I am asking myself:

1. Can this still be reduced to a nicer form if not a closed form?
2. Can the original integral be computed in the complex plane?
3. I want to create an array of $G(q)$ with $q$.
   And I have seen the following:
   $$ G(-q) = G^*(q), $$ where * represents conjugate.
   And $G(q)$ with $q$ increasing from $0$ behaves like a decaying complex exponential.
   Can something be done to approximate this with this information? Can a decaying complex exponential function be formulated to approximate this function but still have all its parameters, such as $b, c, \alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

We can express by infinte series:

$$\int_0^{\infty } y^{\alpha } \exp (-y) \exp (-i b q \exp (-c y)) \, dy=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{(1+c m)^{-1-\alpha } (-i b
   q)^m \Gamma (1+\alpha )}{m!}$$ with **10** terms we have **10**  correct digits.

If $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{>\, 0}
$ then:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, I have already tried it. My application has two issues: $\alpha$ is not always an integer, and hypergeometric functions take a lot of computational resources to compute.

Comment: @CfourPiO Then try the series with few terms.

Comment: Good idea. I will try, thanks a lot!